# What does the last byte after doing `fwrite()` mean?

Tags: c, vim, binary, fwrite

I'm playing around with binary files in **C**, and I can't work out one thing - why does the file end in this byte `00001010` (*that equals a 10*)?

My code is in essence the following (simplified).

```
FILE *test = fopen("file.b", "ab");
int value = 1;
fwrite(&value, sizeof(int), 1, test);
fclose(test);
```

After running the program, `file.b` looks like this (with the help of vim `:%!xxd -b`).

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010
```

The trailing byte happens independent of the type I choose to write.

Comment: The last byte is the newline character which might have been added by vim. What's the length of the file when you list it or write a hexdump?

Comment: You're right, that was a new line. The length is 4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is a newline. vim automatically appends a newline (if the file didn't end in a newline) when you filter it through xxd.

Since you are treating it as a binary file you should tell vim it is a binary file with `vim -b` so the newline isn't added automatically.

Take a look at `:h binary`